# Is it considered as duplicate?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, 410-gone

I'm launching a new website, and I want to bulk delete almost 95% of artilces (+put 410 deleted status to the deleted articles) from the old site, and re-publish them on the new website.

Can my new site be penalized for this? Are those republished articles be considered as duplicate?

Comment: Have you considered doing a 301 redirect instead?

Comment: Your new site won't be penalized in the technical sense of Google blocking duplicate content from their results, since the original URLs will be gone. But if you don't put 301 redirects in place, then none of your old site's search ranking will transfer over.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I thought about about it, but there will be too many redirects and I think it'll hurt seo as well. Plus, no need to transfer since both site will operate separately. One for our SaaS product (eCommerce) + its branded content, and the second one just for blog posts about general eCommerce topics.

Comment: I still think you should do a 301.  Depending on how you look at it 95% need special attention, or 5% need special attention.